# MySQL sum of distinct rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query performing INNER JOINs pulling in a relational cross reference table. So based on the query, I'm getting all (one to many) 'fruits' related to a basket. I need to sum the amount of fruits distinctly.

```
| Banana | 1 |
| Banana | 1 |
| Apple  | 1 |
| Pear   | 1 |
| Pear   | 1 |
| Pear   | 1 |
```

I want the result set to look like this...

```
| Banana | 2 | 
| Apple  | 1 |
| Pear   | 3 |
```

I tried to SUM() fruit in the SELECT with a GROUP BY but the results were not correct (way off). I'm thinking HAVING might need to come into play... anyway, frustrated since this should be pretty easy.

Comment: GROUP BY and COUNT will be your friends here

Comment: Could you add the query or the tables/fields? SUM and GROUP BY should be enough

Comment: Can you give us the table definitions in addition to the sample data?

Comment: A simple GROUP BY should work. You should post your query and some more details.

Comment: What do that `1`s in the first table mean? Are you supposed to sum them? Are they supposed to always be `1`? In the former case you can use `SUM`, otherwise you can ignore them and just use `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only 1's in the second column, try:

```
SELECT fruit, count(fruit)
FROM fruits_table
GROUP BY fruit
```

Comment: Yes.. only 1s in the second column. This works! Thanks! COUNT for the win!

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult with a SUM() and GROUP BY:

```
select a.fruit, sum(a.num) as number
from fruits a
group by a.fruit;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b53a/1

Comment: This is what I tried earlier.. and numbers were all over the place. COUNT was the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? It definitely works. COUNT only works in this case because you have all 1s. If not, you would need to use SUM. However, I'm glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: I'm still doing a little research on my end as well. My counts based on SUM were much higher in my example (not fruit), so could be a result of the INNER JOIN. I was surprised it wasn't working properly on my end initially. But since COUNT works (val is always 1) I'll probably stick with that. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select fruit_name, sum(qte) 
from fruit_table_name
group by fruit_name;
```